# In Elasticsearch, how do you boost a score by the value of a ranking (1st, 2nd, 3rd...) field?

Tags: elasticsearch, relevance

I have a field in the document that is a ranking: where the lower the value, the higher the score it should have. Being first is best, but being last is the worst. So a ranking of 1 is better than 1 million.

So far I've been able to boost on the field value itself with [score_query and field_value_factor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#function-field-value-factor), but it gives the docs with ranks of higher numbers the higher boosts.

```
"field_value_factor": {
  "field": "rank",
  "factor": 1.2,
  "modifier": "sqrt",
  "missing": 1
}
```

Should I be using a different modifier? Or am I going about this completely wrong? Also, I don't want to sort on it alone since I have other factors influencing the `_score`.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything in this question related to [Boost c++ libraries](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/boost/info) -- please don't misuse tags. (As someone who's been frequenting this site for 7+ years, you ought to know this by now)

Comment: Whoops, got tag happy there. Sorry about that. Been a while since I've asked a question though. Thanks for catching that, @DanMašek

Comment: No worries, it can happen :) It was actually kinda funny seeing that on something tagged with "relevance" :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to take a modifier function that reciprocates the `rank` value, i.e. `1 / rank`, so that the higher the rank is, the lower the value will be will and `rank = 1` will get a score of 1. The only one that does it is `reciprocal`

```
"field_value_factor": {
  "field": "rank",
  "factor": 1.2,
  "modifier": "reciprocal",
  "missing": 1
}
```

Comment: Ahhh yeah that makes sense. Thanks!